# Prevent users from view an Excel worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm coding a macro where in the main menu there's a button to access the "Admin" worksheet where one can make important changes. I want only certain users to access this Admin worksheet, and I wonder if there's a way to password-protect **viewing** a worksheet, not just modifying it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
'Update 20140925
Dim xSheetName As String
xSheetName = "Sheet1"
If Application.ActiveSheet.Name = xSheetName Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ActiveSheet.Visible = False
    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    response = Application.InputBox("Password", xTitleId, "", Type:=2)
    If response = "123456" Then
        Application.Sheets(xSheetName).Visible = True
        Application.Sheets(xSheetName).Select
    End If
End If
Application.Sheets(xSheetName).Visible = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This will in effect create a password protected worksheet that will only be visible if the supplied password is correct. 
This answer came from http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2134-excel-password-protect-hidden-sheet.html#a1

Comment: The drawback is that if your users are savvy enough to get into the code, your password is in plain-text. Of course, if you're trying to defend against them, they'll get into the code & muck about to get around the password protection anyway.

Comment: If a user is savvy enough, with a simple module they could wreak havoc on the workbook if they so desired. Any VBA solution to the OP's problem would inevitably have a password that anyone viewing the code could figure out.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for, I just needed a basic level of security. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that helped you out. If this works for you, please accept the answer.